# What are the differences between spring security providers? (Spring Roo 2 M3)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-roo

Well i'm building some personal project to learn spring roo 2. Now i'm struggling with spring security. There is little information about spring roo 2 in google and many relatively useful information on spring boot relating to spring roo.

with the command "security setup" you got the "--provider" option.

This is the description that the help gives you:

> optional --provider: The Spring Security provider to install. Possible values are: `DEFAULT` (default Spring Security configuration provided by Spring Boot will be used), and `SPRINGLETS_JPA` (advanced Spring Security configuration will be included using Springlets JPA Authentication).; default: 'DEFAULT'

I couldn't find the difference between these two options, even on the spring roo M3 reference documentation. Even searching for "Springlets JPA Authentication" gives no information about it.

Anyone has any clue about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the main differences between this two providers:

- `DEFAULT`: Is the default Spring Security auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot when you include the `spring-boot-starter-security` in your project classpath. This is the default option because Spring Roo always tries to generate applications that use the auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot.

  - Selecting this provided the following changes will be applied to your project:

    - `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency will be included to your pom.xml file
  - If you want to know more information about this configuration you should check the [spring boot reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security)
- `SPRINGLETS_JPA`: If you select this provider, the default Spring Security auto-configuration provided by Spring Boot will be used. In addition, this provider will include the [Springlets](https://github.com/DISID/springlets) library to your classpath that provides you some extra starters to auto-configure advanced Spring Security properties. Also, configures the security authentication to use and user from the database instead of the default in-memory authentication provided by Spring Boot auto-configuration. You will be able to manage these configuration using the `application.properties` file and including the properties `springlets.security.auth.in-memory.enabled` and `springlets.security.auth.in-memory.erase-credentials`.

  - Selecting this provided the following changes will be applied to your project:

    - `springlets-boot-starter-authentication` dependency will be included to your pom.xml file
    - `security.enable-csrf=true` property will be included to enable `CSRF`. Know more about CSRF and Spring Security [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html)
  - To know more about the Springlets Security project check [the Springlets project page](https://github.com/DISID/springlets/tree/master/springlets-security)

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks, there is little information about roo 2 out there.

Comment: Remember that Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3 is just a milestone, so maybe the documentation is not complete or some functionalities could need some improvement. We're just working in the RC1 version, that will be available soon!

Comment: nice. Can't wait for the RC! it will be great.